# Failed testing a hash with rspec-rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I'm building a simple API and one of the features is the fact it must inform the users its version. Then I have a Api controller with a version method

```
class ApiController < ApplicationController
  def version
    render :json => {version: '0.0.1'}
  end
end
```

and I also have a route in my **config/routes.rb**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root 'site#index'
  get 'api/version'
end
```

I'm using Rspec and this is the my failing test

```
it 'returns the correct version number (0.0.1 by now)' do
  get :version
  expect(response.body).to eq({'version':'0.0.1'})
end
```

It happens that my test fails (https://i.stack.imgur.com/uk5xJ.jpg)

```
1) ApiController GET #version returns the correct version number (0.0.1 by now)
Failure/Error: expect(response.body).to eq(a)

   expected: {:version=>"0.0.1"}
        got: "{\"version\":\"0.0.1\"}"
```

What is the point here? Should I test against response.body.to_s or something like that?

It seems I'm missing some point, probably an easy one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`response.body` returns a serialized json string whereas `{'version':'0.0.1'}` is a `Hash`.

Your expectation should be `expect(response.body).to eq({'version':'0.0.1'}.to_json)`

or

`expect(JSON.parse(response.body)).to eq({'version':'0.0.1'})`

Comment: Thanks a lot, my friend. I opted for the first possibility and it worked really fine. I'll accept your answer as soon as possible, because SO imposes a delay of ten minutes or so before accepting.

Comment: I am glad I could help.